# Proving Etemadi's inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider $\{X_i\}^n$ independent random variables in some Banach space, for all $t\geq0$ we have:

$$P\left(\max_k \left\|\sum^k_iX_i\right\| > t\right) \leq 3 \max_kP\left(\left\|\sum^k_iX_i\right\| > t/3\right)$$

The proof I've been following first proves the inequality (I can include their proof, but my question is about the next step):

$$P\left(\max_k \left\|\sum^k_iX_i\right\| > t\right) \leq \frac{P(\|\sum^n_iX_i\| > t/3)}{1- \max_kP(\|\sum^n_{i=k+1}X_i\| > 2t/3)}$$

The next step, which I am having trouble following is:
$$\leq \frac{\max_kP(\|\sum^k_iX_i\| > t/3)}{1- 2\max_kP(\|\sum^k_{i=1}X_i\| > t/3)}$$

**What I've tried**

Certainly the numerator on the LHS is less than or equal to the numerator on the RHS, but I cant seem to find a justification for the entire final inequality. I've also tried showing for the denominator that one event contains the other, but I don't think that is the case.

The proof is from Decoupling: From Dependence to Independence

Comment: This document has a very nice proof of the inequality that uses a different approach that is more similar to the previous proofs in the text I am following: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268028043_On_the_maximal_Levy-Ottaviani_inequality_for_sums_of_independent_and_dependent_random_vectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a bit more detail to the comment on this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/940192/352034

Let $S_k = \| \sum_i^k X_i \|$, under this notation (in addition to the inequality for the numerator you've already shown) you want to show:

$$\max_kP(\|S_n - S_k\| > 2r) \leq 2\max_kP(\{\|S_k\| > r\})$$

By triangle inequality:
$$\|S_n - S_k\| > 2r \implies \|S_n\| + \|S_k\| > 2r$$
And so certainly:
$$2\max(\|S_n\|, \|S_k\|) > 2r$$
Which implies:
$$\{\|S_n\| > r\} \cup \{\|S_k\| > r\}$$
So $\|S_n - S_k\| > 2r \implies \{\|S_n\| > r\} \cup \{\|S_k\| > r\}$ so:
$$P(\|S_n - S_k\| > 2r) \leq P(\{\|S_n\| > r\} \cup \{\|S_k\| > r\})$$
Taking max of both sides we have, for $S'_k$ distributed as $S_k$ and independent of it:
$$\max_kP(\|S_n - S_k\| > 2r) \leq \max_kP(\{\|S'_k\| > r\} \cup \{\|S_k\| > r\}) = 2\max_kP(\{\|S_k\| > r\})$$

So now the inequality holds in the correct direction for both the numerator and the denominator.